# How to get user information in *.jsp file

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I am trying to learn something about liferay. Currently I am creating a portlet and in this I am working in *.jsp file where I want to know how to get user information. I found a code that give me a user id. But I wanna other information like userName, userRole(admin, guest, .... )

so my code to get userId is ...

```
<% String userId=request.getUserPrincipal().getName(); %>
<%= userId %> .. to show a variable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current user in Liferay with a JSP like this:

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<theme:defineObjects />

<% User u = themeDisplay.getUser();  %>
```

Find [here](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/User.html) what you can do with the user object

Edit: I totally forgot that, with `<theme:defineObjects />`, you have a user object immediately available. So, even easier:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<theme:defineObjects />

Hello <%=user.getFirstName()%>
```

Comment: To the second part of your comment : I looked at the link you post and there are all possibilities of what to do with "user" ... but thanks again :-)